# How to Access a bitbucket repository after user email is added to repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to invite a user to work with me on a repository but as far as i am aware, for him to access it from his machine he needs to enter an app password even after he is added via email from my end

If this user creates his own app password, cant he just provide himself with all the access control without my intervention? How can i prevent this

Comment: All access control? What do you mean? Why not ask them to fork the repo?

Comment: I want him to be able to push changes to the repositroy but only allow him the permissions i gave to his user group in my project. Currently for him to be able to log in and push changes to bitbucket he needs to log in through the app password as bitbucket requires that since march 2022. When this user goes to create app password , they can select their own permissions